# How can I display Doxygen configuration variables?

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to display values stored in Doxygen configuration variables.  A simple example is the "PROJECT_NAME" variable in the standard Doxyfile configuration file.  How can I display this at an arbitrary location in the code?

I've set up a file called `main.dox` with the following contents:

```
/*!  \mainpage Main Page

- @PROJECT_NAME
- @PROJECT_NAME
- $PROJECT_NAME
- ${PROJECT_NAME}

 */
```

The value for `PROJECT_NAME` is set to `"MY DOCS"` in the standard Doxyfile configuration.  The title displays correctly at the top of the documentation.  On the main page, however, the code above generates the following:

```
*
*
* $PROJECT_NAME
* ${PROJECT_NAME}
```

How can I get it to display `MY DOCS` in the generated output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Doxygen has no way to inject the text of configuration variables into arbitrary points in the code.

You can however write a [custom command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html), an alias/macro that can be used to repeat text in various location. Granted, you'll have to repeat the text of your project name, but it'll be repeated in the configuration file:

```
PROJECT_NAME = Project Name
ALIASES += projname="Project Name"
```

In your documentation comments, you can now use `\projname` or `@projname`.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!  It wouldn't let me provide edits, claiming they were too small, so I am hoping you can make the following tweaks.  To make things work, I needed to change ALIAS to ALIASES, and needed to remove the spaces around that final equal sign.    Once I did that, this solution worked like a charm.